# OAuth2: Handle access_token from an Authentication Server made in Spring Boot in a Resource Server made in Node

Tags: node.js, angular, spring, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm making an OAuth2 Resource Server in Node, and I need to handle de access_token that comes from the AS (made in Spring Boot, which I do not have access to the code because it is made by another team), and the client side is made in Angular 6.

The client stores the token in a cookie, and must be sent to my apis in node to allow doing requests, and this is where I am stuck

I have been trying some libraries with passport.js, but I do not have much experience in Node so I have not been able to handle the cookie in the correct way. Now, I'm having a 500 error and console throw me an strategy error "Maybe you forgot to use cookie-parser?", obviously, I have tried to use cookie-parser but it seems that I am doing something wrong

My custom cookie method in index.js (passport)

```
export const cookie = ({ required } = {}) => (req, res, next) =>
  passport.authenticate('cookie', { session: false }, () => {
    res.cookie('access_token')
  })(req, res, next)

passport.use('cookie', new CookieStrategy({
  cookieName: 'access_token'
},
function (token, done) {
  User.findByToken({ token: token }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err) }
    if (!user) { return done(null, false) }
    return done(null, user)
  })
}))
```

My GET method to retrieve a list of customers:

```
router.get('/',
  cookie({ required: true }),
  query(),
  index)
```

I have tried to handle as a bearer token, because in Angular I send the token to the url's api with headers that takes the token from the cookie (I made the same Resource Server in Spring Boot and it works fine there). Here is the code for token, not cookie:

```
export const token = ({ required } = {}) => (req, res, next) =>
  passport.authenticate('token', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
    if (err || (required && !user) || (required)) {
      return res.status(401).end()
    }
    req.logIn(user, { session: false }, (err) => {
      if (err) return res.status(401).end()
      next()
    })
  })(req, res, next)

passport.use('token', new JwtStrategy({
  secretOrKey: jwtSecret,
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
    ExtractJwt.fromHeader('Authorization: Bearer '),
    ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    ExtractJwt.fromUrlQueryParameter('access_token'),
    ExtractJwt.fromBodyField('access_token'),
    ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('Bearer')
  ])
}, ({ id }, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then((user) => {
    done(null, user)
    return null
  }).catch(done)
}))
```

And I would just have to change the router.get "cookie" for "token"
These are the headers of the request:

```
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: es,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8080/ui/login
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Bearer some_token
Origin: http://localhost:8080
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

I expect the token sent by the client in Angular works for my resource server in node.

Thank you so much!